# Autofac and Background processes

Tags: c#, autofac

I am using WebApi 2 and have the need to fire off a process in the background. I need it to do it's stuff and not affect the current request.

So after some digging around I found that I could just use

```
public void Save(Order model) => Task.Run(() => postmanService.Update(model));
```

I wanted to debug it to make sure it was working, so I change it to this:

```
public void Save(Order model) => await postmanService.Update(model).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

But when I run this I get this error:

> "The ObjectContext instance has been disposed and can no longer be used for operations that require a connection."

I am not sure why this is happening because my **DatabaseContext** is registered like this:

```
builder.RegisterType<DatabaseContext>().As<DbContext>().InstancePerLifetimeScope();
builder.RegisterType<UnitOfWork>().As<IUnitOfWork>().InstancePerLifetimeScope();
builder.RegisterType<CollectionManagerProvider>().As<ICollectionManagerProvider>().InstancePerRequest();
builder.RegisterType<PostmanService>().As<IPostmanService>();
```

The **PostmanService** is what saves the data to the database and it looks like this:

```
public class PostmanService : Service<Postman>, IPostmanService
{
    public PostmanService(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork) : base(unitOfWork)
    {}

    /// <summary>
    /// Save or update a message
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="model"></param>
    public void Save(Postman model)
    {
        if (model.Id == 0)
            Repository.Create(model);
        else
            Repository.Update(model);
    }

    /////////--------- Removed for brevity ---------/////////
}
```

The repository looks like this:

```
public class Repository<T> : IRepository<T> where T : class
{

    // Create our private properties
    private readonly DbContext _context;
    private readonly DbSet<T> _dbEntitySet;

    /// <summary>
    /// Default constructor
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="context">The database context</param>
    public Repository(DbContext context)
    {
        // Assign our context and entity set
        _context = context ?? throw new ArgumentNullException("context");
        _dbEntitySet = context.Set<T>();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Creates an entity
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="model"></param>
    public void Create(T model) => _dbEntitySet.Add(model);

    /// <summary>
    /// Updates an entity
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="model"></param>
    public void Update(T model) => _context.Entry<T>(model).State = EntityState.Modified;

    /////////--------- Removed for brevity ---------/////////
}
```

And finally, the unit of work looks like this:

```
public class UnitOfWork : IUnitOfWork
{
    private readonly Dictionary<Type, object> _repositories;

    // Public properties
    public DbContext Context { get; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Default constructor
    /// </summary>
    public UnitOfWork(DbContext context)
    {
        Context = context;
        _repositories = new Dictionary<Type, object>();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the entity repository
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="TEntity">The entity model</typeparam>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public IRepository<TEntity> GetRepository<TEntity>() where TEntity : class
    {

        // If our repositories have a matching repository, return it
        if (_repositories.Keys.Contains(typeof(TEntity)))
            return _repositories[typeof(TEntity)] as IRepository<TEntity>;

        // Create a new repository for our entity
        var repository = new Repository<TEntity>(Context);

        // Add to our list of repositories
        _repositories.Add(typeof(TEntity), repository);

        // Return our repository
        return repository;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Saves the database changes asynchronously
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public async Task SaveChangesAsync()
    {
        try
        {

            // Save the changes to the database
            await Context.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
        catch (DbEntityValidationException ex) {

            // Retrieve the error messages as a list of strings.
            var errorMessages = ex.EntityValidationErrors.SelectMany(x => x.ValidationErrors).Select(x => x.ErrorMessage);

            // Join the list to a single string.
            var fullErrorMessage = string.Join("; ", errorMessages);

            // Combine the original exception message with the new one.
            var exceptionMessage = string.Concat(ex.Message, " The validation errors are: ", fullErrorMessage);

            // Throw a new DbEntityValidationException with the improved exception message.
            throw new DbEntityValidationException(exceptionMessage, ex.EntityValidationErrors);
        }
    }
}
```

I am not sure if the issue is with the **CollectionManagerProvider** and how that is registered (Because I have registered it as **InstancePerRequest** and techinically the method is being fired on a different thread.

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: One option would be to use `Owned` - http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/advanced/owned-instances.html , and take the responsibility of cleaning it up yourself.

Comment: I did think about that. Can you give me an example or how it might look?

Comment: Looks like using `Owned<IUnitOfWork>` is the answer. I am just doing some tests now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be to use `Owned` - http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/advanced/owned-instances.html , and take the responsibility of disposal upon yourself.

```
public Repository(Owned<DbContext> context)
public PostmanService(Owned<IUnitOfWork> unitOfWork)
```

etc etc

or:

```
builder.RegisterType<DatabaseContext>().As<DbContext>().Inst‌​ancePerLifetimeScope‌​().ExternallyOwned()‌​;
builder.RegisterType<UnitOfWork>().As<IUnitOfWork>().InstancePerLifetimeScope().ExternallyOwned()‌​;
```

etc etc

See:

http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/advanced/owned-instances.html
http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/lifetime/disposal.html

Comment: The externally owned instance worked. Not sure why, but I am happy :D

Comment: It basically works since you took control of it. When you use async / await, the lifetime scope closes earlier than you expect - since it is not kept open for the entire duration of the web request. By using `Owned` you say 'no worries, I'll take of calling Dispose'. So, the container doesn't call Dispose - thus your error goes away.

Comment: I am not using the Owned, just the `.ExternallyOwned`. Does that matter?

Comment: In your context they are basically the same thing. `ExternallyOwned` effectively adds `Owned` implicitly, behind the scenes, to all usages.

Comment: Does that mean that each service that uses the unit of work will create it's own instance (therefore creating a new database connection)?

Comment: `Owned` doesn't impact object creation in any way - my suggestion would make no difference, it will act the same way it did before. It just impacts cleanup (i.e. calling of `Dispose`). That is all it does. The container won't call it - thus it is now your problem. :)